# Error doesn't return to the catch block of the calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, promise

The catch block from the called function doesn't return promise to the calling function.

```
copyFunction = () => {
    this.Service.callCopyFnctn().then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        //This doesn't get invoked 
        console.log(error);
    });
  };


this.copyRetries = 0;
public callCopyFnctn = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var dfd = this.$q.defer();
    let copyHttpRequest: ng.IRequestConfig = {
      'url': //url,
      'method': 'GET',
      'headers': {}
    };

    this.$http(copyHttpRequest).then((response) => {
      dfd.resolve(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
// exponentialWaitTime will wait for specific time after making the retry call.
      this.exponentialWaitTime(2 * (this.copyRetries + 1) * 1000).then(() => {
        if (this.copyRetries <= 2 && (error.status === 503 || error.status === 504)) {
          this.copyRetries++;
          this.callCopyFnctn();
        } else {
          dfd.reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
    return dfd.promise;
  };
```

When we get the error from `callCopyFnctn` When the call goes to the else block and `dfd.reject(error)` gets called but then the call doesn't return to the calling function catch block i.e; doesn't throw the promise.

Dont understand what the issue is.

Comment: You are missing `return` statements in the catch for `$http`

Comment: as you are conditionally re-calling `this.callCopyFnctn();`, guess what? the promise returned by the initial call to `callCopyFnctn();` is never resolved or rejected ... try `dfd.resolve(this.callCopyFnctn());` ... if `$q.defer();` is Promise/A+ compliant, then you'll be fine - though, why you're using `$q.defer` is a mystery - what's wrong with native Promises? in fact, why are you wrapping a function that already returns a Promise `$q.defer`

Comment: I'd do it like this https://pastebin.com/C4VjWYpr - or with async/await, like https://pastebin.com/XMZLBidS